# How to run a gitlab child pipeline only on changes in merge requests?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

According to the documentation, parent-child pipelines should work well with `rules` - so i'm trying to setup a parent-child pipeline, where the child pipelines only run when something has actually changed in the sub-service. Using the following setup:

main .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yml
trigger_service_a:
  trigger:
    include: service_a/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - service_a/*
      when: always
```

service_a/.gitlab-ci.yml:

```yml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - service_a/*
      when: always

service_a:
  script:
    - echo "run"
```

However, when i push in a merge request without changes inside service_a, the pipeline fails with : `trigger_service_a - failed - (downstream pipeline can not be created, Pipeline filtered out by workflow rules.)`

Even if i change something in the service_a, i still get the same error.

How can i trigger child-pipelines in branches and merge requests only when something has changed in the sub-service?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the same rules for both parent and child pipelines? You are just triggering the child service `if anything changes on files inside the child service directory`
So, just define rules on child pipeline... It will automatically trigger if any changes happen on `service_a/*`

Comment: I tried to put this rule only in the child pipeline, but then i get the same error when service_a has no changes . if it has changes, it runs successfully.